# FadeIn in ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the markup below that shows log entries. When the user does an action, I add an entry in logs like so: `logs.push(log)`.

```
 <div ng-repeat="log in logs track by $index">
        <div class="logEntry">
           {{log.text}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

This works fine, however I would like to add an effect when the entry appears on the UI. I tried with jQuery `$(".logEntry").fadeIn();` but this doesn't work, may be because I'm mixing it with ng-repeat. Any ideas how this can be done? Either jQuery or AngularJS animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngAnimate`, just keep in mind it's a dependency you need to add:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="log in logs" class="logEntry">
    <div>
       {{log}}
    </div>
</div>
<button ng-click="addLog();">Add log</button>
```

**Ctrl:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var count = 1;
    $scope.logs = ["log " + count++];

    $scope.addLog = function () {
        $scope.logs.push("log " + count++);
    }

}
```

**CSS:**

```
 .logEntry.ng-enter 
  {
      -webkit-transition: 1s;
      transition: 1s;
      opacity:0;
  }
  .logEntry.ng-enter-active 
  {
      opacity:1;
  }


  .logEntry.ng-leave 
  {
      -webkit-transition: 1s;
      transition: 2s;
  }
  .logEntry.ng-leave-active 
  {
      opacity:0;
  }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11325/)

Comment: how do I relate the CSS to the div? I don't see you using the logEntry class.

Comment: You don't need to. `ng-enter` takes care of that.

Comment: but if I don't relate the effect with the div, the effect will apply to all the divs and I don't want that.

Comment: @pgschr See updated question (fiddler + CSS + HTML). I moved the logEntry to the `ng-repeat` element and adjusted the CSS so only your logEntry will fade in.

Answer (score 0):

your using jquery animation, If u want apply this animation you have to call

angular digest cycle manually after applying effect...For that u can use

```
 $scope.apply() function.
```

Otherwise use ng-Animate...Its a good choice for animations

Comment: "Let me tell you a story. Once upon a time..."